# How fix error "Incorrect magic number" on wordpress generate voucher PDF?

Tags: linux, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, pdf-generation

platform: wordpress + woocommerce + PDF Product Vouchers

When generating a voucher, an error sometimes pops up:
could not generate voucher pdf: cannot create voucher: incorrect magic number (0)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the plugin: mail log. After disabling, everything works without errors.
Probably the problem is in the incorrect function of sending letters.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because your hosting server has an incorrect SSL certificate set for OpenSSL, so when this third-party library [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) (which is being used by SkyVerge) sends a `file_get_contents()` request to this [URL](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo%20Narrow:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap) to load Google fonts, it throws this error `SSL: Connection reset by peer`.

The quick solution to fix it is to put this snippet below in your `functions.php` or any code snippet plugin like WPCode, which will unload Google Fonts and use the default fonts:

```
add_filter('wc_pdf_product_vouchers_available_google_fonts', function(){
    return [];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Skyverge product, it's actual issue. Skyverge is looking for a solution. But if ASAP, then try to replace with PDF plugin version 3.8, not 3.9 and newer.

Comment: thanks i tried this but don't help me ((